# can MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(); be use in normal java class?

Tags: android

i am creating an app to get Uri of an image and do some processing on the image on Java class.
once i got the URi, i will pass it to a java class to get the image into bitmap and process it. my question is,

can MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(); be use in normal java class?

if cant, is there other way to convert my Uri into Bitmap?

cuz from wat i know passing bitmap around will cause out of memory error.

Comment: Either the bitmap fits into memory or it doesn't. What do you mean by "normal java class"? As opposed to what?

Comment: erm, normal java class is the java class that i created to process the image. like:
public class process image{
        //code to process the image
}

Comment: There should be no particular problems unless your bitmaps are very large. If you're concerned about accidentally keeping references to bitmaps that should be GC'ed, you can call `recycle()` for the bitmaps when you're done with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use it, whilst working on Android Application.

Comment: i tried it and it wont work. i think the error is caused in the contentResolver part in MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, Uri). i put null as value since the class cuz i get error when putting the classname.this.getContentResolver() in it. even when i inherit the Activity method.